# Numpy : index 2 dimensions at once

Tags: numpy, indexing

I want to assign new values to an array, on positions given by some indexes. An exemple will be more clear :

```
import numpy as np

#Dimensions
N = 25
n = 50
d = 100
k = 3
p = 7

A = np.random.uniform(size=(N,n,d,d))

A_new_values = np.random.uniform(size=(N,n,k,p))
indexes_new_values = np.random.choice(np.arange(d),size=k*p,replace=False).reshape((k,p))

print(A[:,:,indexes_new_values].shape)
```

I wanted the last line to yield `(N,n,k,p)`, to be able to assign new values as :

```
A[:,:,indexes_new_values] = A_new_values
```

But this yield an error. How can i assign `A_new_values` to the propper places in `A` ?

Comment: Have a look at `indexes_new_values`, it has repeating values... So where exactly do you want to insert the new values? Please show an example.

Comment: Well, suppose it has no repeating values. I drew random values to build my MWE but my true data (which is complex to expose...) has none. 

I edited the MWE to correct this.

Comment: Which index in `A` should one of the elements of `indexes_new_values` be? After all, while `indexes_new_values` is two-dimensional, its *values* are just single numbers. So if `indexes_new_values[2,2]` is, for example, `33`, what should that index in `A`? Should it be `A[:,:,33,33]`?

Comment: It *would* be possible to index the last two dimension of `A_new_values` with `indexes_new_values` instead, since `A_new_values` last two dimensions are completely covered by `indexes_new_values`. But then you'd want `indexes_new_values` to be a boolean array instead.

Comment: I believe your question is inconsistent. Either you want to generate `k * p` _scattered_ indices along the last two dimensions, but in this case you'd have to generate indices up to `d**2`, not `d`, and apply the existing answer (or equivalently, generate `k * p` _pairs_ of indices up to `d`). If instead you want to "slice" a `k x p` subarray along the last two dimensions, you have to generate `k + p` indices up to `d` each instead (note the addition instead of multiplication). It would probably help to figure this out if you go down to 2d arrays of shape `(d1,d2)` and make it work for that.

Comment: I think you a right Andras, my question is inconsistent. What i wanted was what proposed @00 in it's first comment. But again, this question is ill-posed.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, I think you can do what you want with [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html):

```py
import numpy as np

#Dimensions
N = 25
n = 50
d = 100
k = 3
p = 7

np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.uniform(size=(N, n, d, d))
A_new_values = np.random.uniform(size=(N, n, k, p))
indexes_new_values = np.random.choice(np.arange(d), size=k * p, replace=False).reshape((k, p))
np.put_along_axis(A, indexes_new_values.reshape(1, 1, -1, 1), A_new_values.reshape(N, n, -1, 1), axis=2)
print(np.all(A[10, 20, indexes_new_values[1, 5]] == A_new_values[10, 20, 1, 5]))
# True
```

Comment: I suspect they'd need to generate indices up to `d**2` for that, not `d`.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Ah, I think I see what you mean, that `k` and `p` are supposed to correspond to the last two `d`-sized dimensions of `A`? But then I'm not sure how it would work, what exactly is the relationship between `indexes_new_values[i, j]`, `A_new_values[:, :, i, j]` and `A`...

Comment: See my comment on the question. It's either your interpretation with `d**2`-sized or pair-of-`d`-sized indices with fancy indexing, or it's a subarray definition a'la [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html).